# How to automatically update 'Periods' columns with the data results running Stored Procedure

Tags: sql

This is the partial script of the stored procedure.
I want to be able to automatically update (data results below) the next 'P4' (and so on) columns count:

```
/*
RESULTS:
66,
221,
0
*/


DECLARE
@APP_TOTAL INT
, @DB_TOTAL INT
, @OS_TOTAL INT
, @YEAR INT

SET @APP_TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM [db_eCAM].[dbo].[tbl_SecChecks]
WHERE LAYER = 'APP' AND [ENABLE] = 1)
PRINT @APP_TOTAL

SET @DB_TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM [db_eCAM].[dbo].[tbl_SecChecks]
WHERE LAYER = 'DB' AND [ENABLE] = 1)
PRINT @DB_TOTAL

SET @OS_TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM [db_eCAM].[dbo].[tbl_SecChecks]
WHERE LAYER = 'OS' AND [ENABLE] = 1)
PRINT @OS_TOTAL

SET @YEAR = 2013
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
update mytable
    set p4 = case
        when description = 'APP_TOTAL' then @APP_TOTAL
        when description = 'DB_TOTAL' then @DB_TOTAL
        when description = 'OS' then @OS_TOTAL
    end
where description in ('APP_TOTAL', 'DB_TOTAL', 'OS');
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f575c/1

To make the period # dynamic, you might use dynamic SQL like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f575c/5